# Remove lateral margins only in header latex

Tags: header, latex, margins

I'm creating a report using latex and I want to remove the lateral spaces in the header only I tried to remove the margins using `\newgeometry{left=0cm,right=0cm}` but I affects to all the page and I only want in the header, I attach image.

To insert the image I used:

\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{img/AboutMe-Informe-Microbiota-17.jpg}}

[image]